# Config file masks

Tags: go, configuration, 12factor, viper-go

We deploy services as docker containers using Marathon.  The containers include a base config file, Marathon pulls an environment config file (which has a subset of the base keys) at deployment time so when the app starts it has;

- environment.toml
- config.toml

when reading the config we need to conflate the values in both files to a single set, effectively masking/shadowing the values present in both files with those in the environment file.

I didn't find this functionality in the Viper docs.  Unless I have missed something it seems my options are;

- Write a package that uses Viper to read both files and perform the conflation.
- Extend Viper

Before I start writing code, is there already a mechanism for doing this?

Comment: I haven't read files with viper, I've only used it behind cobra for parsing config flags. However I use it like `serverCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&Cfg.BindAddress, "bind", "b", "0.0.0.0", "the listen interface")`, maybe you can similarly write the values of both configs into shared pointers?